# Modifying value of object pointed by a shared pointer

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have recently started working with shared pointers and need some help. I have a vector 1 of shared pointers to some objects. I need to construct another vector 2 of shared pointers to the same objects, so that modifying vector 2 would result in modification of vector 2.
This is how my code looks like:
This works fine

```
class A
{
    public:
    int a;
    A (int x) {
      a = x;
    }
    int print() {
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<A> ab = make_shared<A>(100);
    cout<< ab->print();
    
    shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<A>>> vec1 = make_shared<vector<shared_ptr<A>>>(1);
    shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<A>*>> vec2 = make_shared<vector<shared_ptr<A>*>>();
    vec2->push_back(&(*vec1)[0]);
    for (shared_ptr<A>* obj : *vec2) {
        *obj = make_shared<A>(100);
    }
    cout << (*((*vec1)[0])).a;   // Prints 100
    return 0;
}
```

But this gives a SEGV at the last line since vec1 is not populated:

```
class A
{
    public:
    int a;
    A (int x) {
      a = x;
    }
    int print() {
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{   
    shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<A>>> vec1 = make_shared<vector<shared_ptr<A>>>(1);
    shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<A>>> vec2 = make_shared<vector<shared_ptr<A>>>();
    vec2->push_back((*vec1)[0]);
    for (shared_ptr<A> obj : *vec2) {
        obj = make_shared<A>(100);
    }
    cout << (*((*vec1)[0])).a;   // SIGSEGV
    return 0;
}
```

I want to understand why vec1 was not populated in the 2nd one and also would like to know if there is any other way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: `(*vec1)[0]` causes undefined behaviour - the vector managed by `vec1` is empty but you try to access the first element

Comment: In the first code, `vec2` is currently a vector of raw pointers to shared_ptr, which makes no sense - if you intend these to point to elements of vec1, they will all dangle any time `vec1` reallocates internal storage. One of the whole reasons for using shared_ptr in the first place is to avoid the problems of raw pointers, so I would strongly recommend not using raw pointers.  Why don't you just have `vec2` be the same type as `vec1` and both vectors' corresponding elements manage the same target ?

Comment: So the requirement for my project is like this - vec2 needs to contain the pointer to entries missing in vec1. Eg: If vec1 is {a, _ , b, _ } then vec2 needs to contain pointers to 2nd and 4th element of vec1. vec1 is a vector of shared pointers to objects of a class. How can this be done in a safe way?

Comment: There is no magical way to alter `vec1.size()` from the outside, without calling any member functions of `vec1`; if that's what you are asking. There's nothing you can do with `vec2` to make `vec1[0]` valid; at some point, one way or another, you need to call `vec1.push_back` or similar. In light of this, it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you should step back and describe the problem you are trying to solve, rather than the solution you came up with but can't make to work. See also: [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: In the example, `vec1` is of size 0. Where and how does it become of size 10?

Comment: I edited the question to initialize it to 1 for example. That is where we initialize it to 10

Comment: just push `shared_ptr` to the objects in question into vec2?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be the 2nd approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the setup described in the comments could be:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int a;
    A(int a): a(a) {}
};

int main()
{   
    auto p_vec1 = make_shared<vector<shared_ptr<A>>>();
    auto p_vec2 = make_shared<vector<shared_ptr<A>>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        p_vec1->push_back( make_shared<A>(i) );

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        p_vec2->push_back( (*p_vec1)[i * 2] ); 
    
    (*p_vec1)[2]->a = 213;
    std::cout << (*p_vec2)[1]->a << '\n';    // print 213

    return 0;
}
```

In case you are unaware, the "outer" `shared_ptr` is unnecessary, you could just use two vectors .